# Gulp watch doesn't finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    return gulp.src('./themes/custom/sebastian/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./themes/custom/sebastian/images'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./themes/custom/sebastian/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./themes/custom/sebastian/css'));
});

gulp.task('uglify', function() {
    return gulp.src('./themes/custom/sebastian/lib/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./themes/custom/sebastian/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('./themes/custom/sebastian/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch('./themes/custom/sebastian/lib/*.js', gulp.series('uglify'));
    gulp.watch(
        [
            './themes/custom/sebastian/css/style.css',
            './themes/custom/sebastian/**/*.twig',
            './themes/custom/sebastian/js/*.js'
        ],
        function(files) {
            livereload.changed(files);
        }
    );
});
```

> [18:40:58] Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-8.7.9\drupal-8.7.9\themes\custom\sebastian\gulpfile.js
>
> [18:40:58] Starting 'watch'...

Why does it not finish the watch?

Gulp watch doesn't create a css folder in the sebastian folder.

Answer (score 1):

The `watch` task doesn't finish because you didn't terminate that task - like you did with the `return` statements in the other tasks.  **But that is a good thing.**

You do not want the `watch` task to terminate - you want it to keep watching files as you edit them and the `watch` task will then trigger the other tasks.

The `watch` task on its own - like on first run - will not trigger the `sass` task until you edit a `.scss` file that it is watching.   As soon as you do that, the `sass` task should be triggered and your output `.css` file be created.

There are options to have the `watch` task be triggered on first run if that is really what you wish.  But it doesn't sound like that is your issue.

Comment: Can you detail what you mean by "There are options to have the watch task be triggered on first run if that is really what you wish".  I'm doing something very similar to the OP, calling this in a post-build event. The function returns, but the build never finishes.

Answer (score 1):

- add function callback in functions task

```
gulp.task('watch', function(callback) {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('./themes/custom/sebastian/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch('./themes/custom/sebastian/lib/*.js', gulp.series('uglify'));
    gulp.watch(
        [
            './themes/custom/sebastian/css/style.css',
            './themes/custom/sebastian/**/*.twig',
            './themes/custom/sebastian/js/*.js'
        ],
        function(files) {
            livereload.changed(files);
        }
    );
callback()
});
```